# Package nginx-core not configured yet.Sub-process :/user/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssh, dpkg

I tried installing `ssh` in another user in my ubuntu 16.04.But I recieved this error:

```
After this operation, 99.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ssh all 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 [7,070 B]
Fetched 7,070 B in 2s (2,659 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package ssh.
(Reading database ... 244468 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ssh_1%3a7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking ssh (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up ssh (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove completely `nginx` and `ssh` and then install them one by one. However, this question is more appropriate for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Anyone knows answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case reason was

```
-- Unit nginx.service has begun starting up.
Oct 31 22:04:33 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 31 22:04:33 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 31 22:04:34 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 31 22:04:34 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 31 22:04:35 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 31 22:04:35 alexeymiller nginx[14157]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Oct 31 22:04:35 alexeymiller systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 31 22:04:35 alexeymiller systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Probably you have apache2 installed which is using 80 port.
Remove apache2 and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need apache 2 installed remove it

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check out

```
root@sg1:/var/www# service nginx status

* nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-02-13 00:51:20 UTC; 5min ago
  Process: 5861 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 5853 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 13 00:51:18 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Feb 13 00:51:18 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Feb 13 00:51:19 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Feb 13 00:51:19 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech nginx[5861]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 13 00:51:20 sg1.tech systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@sg1:/var/www#
```

service Apache2 stop
service nginx start